# Android DDMS fake call disabled

Tags: android, ddms

I'm trying to make a fake phone call via DDMS to my Android emulator. Usually this is not a problem, but now the controls are all grayed out in the Emulator Control view. Please see the screenshot below. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I'm not able to type anything in the input boxes, altho they appear to be ready for input.

[image: DDMS Emulator control]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the new features in the emulator enabling me to call. The "Extended controls" is in the overflow menu on the emulator controls.

[image: Overflow menu]

[image: Extended controls]

Comment: Bravo! thank you! your answer is the best from 1000 that i saw in internet. Nobody said about this button "---" on emulator. Great.